# Getting wrong datetime after resampling

Tags: python, datetime, merge, time-series, resampling

I want to create missing records from a time serie of % humidity.

```
                   datetime  humidite
0   2019-07-09 08:30:00        87
1   2019-07-09 11:00:00        87
2   2019-07-09 17:30:00        82
3   2019-07-09 23:30:00        80
4   2019-07-11 06:15:00        79
5   2019-07-19 14:30:00        39
6   2019-07-21 00:00:00        80
```

I tried to index with existing datetime (result at this step is ok) :

```
humdt["datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(humdt["datetime"])
humdt = humdt.set_index("datetime")

                         humidite
datetime
2019-07-09 08:30:00        87
2019-07-09 11:00:00        87
2019-07-09 17:30:00        82
2019-07-09 23:30:00        80
2019-07-11 06:15:00        79
2019-07-19 14:30:00        39
```

Then reindex at 15 min frequency (my target frequency) :

```
    humdt.resample("15min").asfreq()


                     humidite
datetime
2019-06-26 10:00:00      34.0
2019-06-26 10:15:00      33.0
2019-06-26 10:30:00      32.0
2019-06-26 10:45:00      31.0
2019-06-26 11:00:00      30.0
2019-06-26 11:15:00      29.0
```

As a result, I get wrong starting time and values, just frequency is respected.

Can you help me please ? I also tried to merge a range of datetime defined as my expected records with my data and it doesn't work. Thank you !!!

Comment: this looks weird... unfortunately, I cannot reproduce it (Python 3.8.3, pandas 1.0.3). By the way, a frequency of 15 min will leave you with quite a lot of NaNs in the output if the input timeseries is that sparse

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, to be more precise I have 36 stations and 6 meteorological parameters to analyze. To do that, I need some homogenization. In total my reformatted series have to contain more than 24 200 records (or rows). No idea how to make corresponding table from expected datetimes to actually recorded by merging ? When I merge I obtain the right number of records but all values are at NaN, even the recorded ?!

Comment: Hi Emilie I am not able to reproduce either. Running your exact same code gives the expected result. Are you expecting floats after resampling? I am not sure why also the `humidite` would change to 34.0?

Comment: Hi JQadrad, thank you. What expected is recorded values (87,87,82...) and NaN between them, a row each 15min. I add requested information about python version: 2.7.5 and pandas 0.24.2. Sound not good ? I use a shared machine, so I m not free to change versions because my colleagues have their proper requirements.

Comment: other way : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61807559/getting-wrong-values-after-merging-two-dataframe-on-datetime